# Editar Formulario con javascript

Tags: php, javascript, sql

Tengo un formulario que recoge información sobre la Site y las Lans.
Una site contiene varias lanes, la cosa es que no controlo para nada javascript, todo lo he hecho con HTML5 y PHP, y querría que dependiendo de que Site hayas escogido, que te salgan las lanes de ese site en específico.

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

[image: form]

En la SELECT de Site me salen todas las sites que tengo:

[image: sites]

En la SELECT de lans me salen todas las lanes, y me gustaría que me salieran solo las lanes que están relacionadas con la site que haya elegido arriba.

[image: lanes]

Os dejo una captura de la base de datos:

[image: BD]

Código:

```
<form>
 <select name="site">
  <option value='2'></option>
   /*hay mas option que no voy a copiar porque están dentro de un for en php*/
 </select>
 <select name="site">
  <option value='2'></option>
   /*hay mas option que no voy a copiar porque están dentro de un for en php*/
 </select>

</form>
```

Comment: Podrías agregar el código en vez de imágenes, es más fácil replicar el ejemplo, gracias.

Comment: Saludos, tal como te comentan es mejor agregar tu código de como estas mostrando o armando tu form es decir tu html y php para darte una mejor respuesta

Comment: Gracias por comentar, no he adjuntado el formulario original, sino que he creado uno nuevo con el que podáis mirarlo sin que os duela la cabeza (el original está lleno de variables php), pero la pregunta sigue siendo la misma @DiegoAvila

Comment: Creo yo que lo más conveniente es hacer un query al seleccionar el site. Así solo traes los registros que son relacionados al site y con el resultado muestras  las Lan

Comment: Para hacer lo que requieres necesitas de `AJAX`, así al momento de seleccionar tu **Site** haces una consulta a la **BD**  con un `select` y traes las *LANS* que le correspondan y las agregar al `SELECT` de *LANS*, necesitarías investigar cómo utilizar `AJAX`, puedes hacerlo netamente puro con `JS` o utilizando `jQuery`, sé que esto es nuevo para ti, pero **la práctica hace al maestro**.

Comment: lo que buscas se llama select dependientes te sugiero rvisar el siguiente link e intentarlo cuando tengas errores con ello edita tu pregunta: https://programacion.net/articulo/selects_dependientes_utilizando_jquery-_ajax_y_php_1740

Comment: Gracias a todos por los comentarios, me imaginaba que los tiros irían por AJAX, pero quería asegurarme de que no había otra opción